# Does Azure Active Directory B2C work with Oauth or Open ID?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I successfully implemented Azure Active Directory for user management/authentication/login in a web app, following this example:
[Azure Sample AAD with Flask](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-flask-graphapi-web-v2)

I decided to try Azure Active Directory B2C because of its integration for the various social apps. However, I could not get the flask app to work using OAuth 2.0, since Azure AD B2C does not seem to be compatible with OAuth 2.0. I found some documentation that states Azure AD B2C requires Open ID Connect.

Could you please confirm whether Azure Active Directory B2C requires Open ID Connect, or whether it works with OAuth 2.0 as well?

Thanks

Comment: one should be aware that there's a difference between OpenID [1.0|2.0} and OpenID Connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-protocols), Azure AD B2C supports both OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 protocols.

> **Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C provides identity as a service
>   for your apps by supporting two industry standard protocols: OpenID
>   Connect and OAuth 2.0**. The service is standards-compliant, but any two
>   implementations of these protocols can have subtle differences.

Comment: Thank you. The documentation also states: "We recommend OpenID Connect if you're building a web application that is hosted on a server and accessed through a browser. If you want to add identity management to your mobile or desktop applications by using Azure AD B2C, you should use OAuth 2.0 rather than OpenID Connect." [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc). I am trying to find out if this is a *must* use Open Id Connect or *recommended* really means it is optional.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, I am building a Flask web app, so the *recommended* approach is Open Id Connect. However, the apparent *required* approach for native apps (mobile or desktop) is OAuth 2.0. So, I need clarification as to whether the *recommended* approach for web apps is really *required*. I successfully used Flask-OAuthlib with Azure AD, but when I switched to Azure AD B2C, Flask-OAuthlib had issues with AAD B2C. I would prefer to use Flask-OAuthlib, but am not sure if I *must* use flask-oidc for Open Id Connect, and that was the cause of the errors.

Comment: To respond if anyone else is having a similar issue, the answer is that Open Id Connect is *not* required for web apps.

Answer (score 4):

Azure AD B2C supports both OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 as noted in the official [reference protocols documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-protocols).

To be able to sign-in users with Azure AD B2C using OAuth 2.0 and Flask, you'll need to adapt the sample to follow the OAuth 2.0 approach used in this sample: [An Android application with Azure AD B2C using OAuth](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-nodejs-webapi/). Key things you'll need to adapt:

- You'll need to specify the B2C authorization and token endpoints: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/TENANT_NAME/POLICY_NAME/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`. [Example from Android sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-nodejs-webapi/blob/master/android-oauth-client/samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/oauth/samples/azureb2c/Azureb2cConstants.java#L7-L14)
- You'll need to add your application/client ID as a scope. [Example from Android sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-nodejs-webapi/blob/67203f6d644c04f93939fe458a8fb0c77e7b6d25/android-oauth-client/samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/oauth/samples/azureb2c/SimpleOAuth2Activity.java#L183)
- You won't be able to call the Graph's /me endpoint for token validation and to get user details. You'll need to validate the token and extract the claims from it yourself (ideally through a good JWT open source library since this isn't trivial, unfortunately I don't know any that I can recommend at this time).

**EDIT**

I've created a [python sample for Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-flask-web-b2c) and used [python-jose](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose) for token validation and claim retrieval. Check it out.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth to not that Azure Active Directory B2C (AAD B2C) supports *both* [**OpenID Connect**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc) and [**OAuth 2.0**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code) in that it uses these two protocols to exchange information and secure tokens. However, AAD B2C ["extends"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-protocols#policies) these protocols by introducing Policies to handle the user experience for Sign-up, Sign-in and general account management.

What does this mean? First of, it means that you cannot create your own sign-up/sign-in experience, you are restricted to redirecting the user to the right policy ([which you to some extent can customize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization)). You cannot create your own sign-up/-in UI for this and you are restricted to styling/branding the provided web-based UI for this.

So in order to *Authenticate* using AAD B2C you could follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc), it should be easy enough to adapt to Python. You simply redirect the user to the `/authorize` endpoint of the AAD B2C and then [validate the JWT you receive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#validate-the-idtoken)